# Limit max-width of a background image in CSS

Tags: css, image, background, cover, background-size

I'm making a website and using a background image in a div.

The background image itself is using "cover" as its size. The div itself has a max width, as does its parent div.

However, when I test on larger screens, it continues to stretch. The divs themselves do not, they stay bounded at their upper levels, but the image continues to grow as the window expands.

I've tried using a width of 100%, which has the same problem. I've tried limiting the img.bg size, I've tried changing the background-size to cover contain and 100% cover, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Here's where it's at right now. On 1920x1080 browsers, the image will stretch all the way to 1920, even though I can only see 1300px of it.

```
img.bg {
max-width: 1300px;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url("images/headerimage2.jpg");
  height: 350px;
  max-width: 1300px;
  min-width: 650px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The HTML where it's going I invoke with just this:

```
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Comment: please provide minimal html required to add snippet to your code so we can se the example

Comment: Just added HTML. Let me know if you need more context, but that's technically all I'm doing to call this section.

Comment: remove background-attachment: fixed

Comment: Removing the background attachment DOES fix it, but then it can't do the parallax scrolling effect. Are these two things incompatible?